# Using two combobox to set conditions for a search in a database and displaying in jtable

Tags: java, mysql

I need to display the details of students in a particular stream of a schoolclass in Jtable from a database containing all the names of students in the school. I have two jComboboxes, on to select which class and the other to select the stream. I am asking for a way to define these two conditions in order to display all the students in a particular stream in a jtable. I apologize in advance if my code is messy.

```
public Classes() {
    initComponents();
    show_student();
}    

public Connection getConnection() {
    Connection con = null;

    try {
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sms", "root", "");
    } catch(Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
    }
    return con;
}

public ArrayList<Individualclass> studentList(String ValToSearch) {
    ArrayList<Individualclass> list = new 
    ArrayList<Individualclass>();

    Statement st;
    ResultSet rs;

    try {
        Connection con=getConnection();
        st = con.createStatement();
        String searchQuery = "SELECT * FROM `students` WHERE CONCAT(`firstName`, `surname`, `otherNames`, `regNo`) LIKE '%"+ValToSearch+"%'";
        rs = st.executeQuery("searchQuery ");

        Individualclass ic;

        while(rs.next()) {
            ic = new Individualclass(
                    rs.getString("firstName"),
                    rs.getString("surname"),
                    rs.getString("otherNames"),
                    rs.getInt("regNo")        

            );
            list.add(ic);
        }
    } catch(Exception ex){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage());
    }
    return list;
}

public void findStudents() {

}   

private void sClassActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_sClassActionPerformed
    try {
        Connection con = getConnection();
        String fetch_row = "SELECT * FROM students where sClass=?";
        PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(fetch_row);
        pst.setString(1, (String) sClass.getSelectedItem());
        ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();

        while(rs.next()) {
            Individualclass ic = new Individualclass(rs.getString("firstName"),rs.getString("surname"),rs.getString("otherNames"),rs.getInt("regNo"));
        }
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage());
    }
}//GEN-LAST:event_sClassActionPerformed

private void streamActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_streamActionPerformed
    try {
        Connection con = getConnection();
        String fetch_row = "SELECT * FROM students where stream=?";
        PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(fetch_row);
        pst.setString(1, (String)stream.getSelectedItem());
        ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();

        while(rs.next()) {
            Individualclass ic = new Individualclass(rs.getString("firstName"),rs.getString("surname"),rs.getString("otherNames"),rs.getInt("regNo"));
        }
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage());
    }
}//GEN-LAST:event_streamActionPerformed

public void show_student() {
    ArrayList<Individualclass> list = new ArrayList<Individualclass>();
    DefaultTableModel model =  (DefaultTableModel)jTable_Display_Student.getModel();
    Object [] row = new Object[13];
    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        row[0] = list.get(i).getFirstName();
        row[1] = list.get(i).getsurname();
        row[2] = list.get(i).getOtherNames();
        row[3] = list.get(i).getregNo();

        model.addRow(row);
    }
}
```